# How to make a WPF datagrid autoscroll to the top automatically when new items are added?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on a datagrid that is a feed of events being collected every 15-20 seconds and there are hundreds being stored in the datagrid at once. I need a way to have the datagrid automatically scroll automatically to the top when new events have been added so that the user doesn't have to scroll themselves as this is a monitoring application that is generally just kept on a side monitor. So far the only way I have been able to replicate the behavior I want is disabling the RowVirtualization. However, when I do that scrolling down to older events becomes nearly impossible in a reasonable amount of time and slows down the entire UI.

Here is the datagrid I am using. It is not contained in any other control besides a grid, except the entire view is within a avalonDock DockingManager pane.

```
<DataGrid
            Name="EventsView_DataGrid"
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultManager.EventsRepository.Events}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            MouseDoubleClick="EventsView_DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Computer"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=ComputerName, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Source ID"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=SourceId, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Source"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=SourceName, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Time"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=EventTime, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="Message"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=EventMessage, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Solution"
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=EventSolution, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True, FallbackValue=...}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Here is what the datagrid looks like when ran.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the event AddingNewItem:

```
<DataGrid Name="EventsView_DataGrid"
        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultManager.EventsRepository.Events}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        MouseDoubleClick="EventsView_DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
        AddingNewItem="EventsView_DataGrid_AddingNewItem">
         ...
        </DataGrid>
```

And use ScrollIntoView:

```
private void EventsView_DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (EventsView_DataGrid.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(EventsView_DataGrid, 0) as Decorator;
            if (border != null)
            {
                var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
                if (scroll != null) scroll.ScrollToHome();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and with the virtualization on it still requires input to scroll to the new items at the top.

Comment: @LandonGeorge I edited my answer, try it, it will scroll the grid to the top. If it does not work, change the function to be called every time the ItemsSource is refreshed.

Comment: How do I attach the function so it gets called when the itemsource is updated?

Comment: Can you see if this question can help you:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136613/how-can-i-execute-code-when-value-of-a-variable-changes-in-c) ?